# How to use XLOOKUP to find greater than OR less than in the same formula?

Tags: excel, vlookup, xlookup

In essence I want to find the value of a cell that's either greater than my search key or less than, whichever is closest.

All the `XLOOKUP` formulas either allow you to search the closest large or the closest small number, not both. There's no comparing, which is what I want to do with my formula.

Cell value: 34512.95

```
=XLOOKUP(G4,sheet2!$K$3:$K$534,sheet2!$L$3:$L$534,,-1) = results in 34509.7
=XLOOKUP(G4,sheet2!$K$3:$K$534,sheet2!$L$3:$L$534,,1) = results in 34527.9
```

I'm only using `XLOOKUP` because it's easy, if there's another formula that works better I'm all for it.

example dataset

sheet1

| Chain | Transponder | Delta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 34512.95 | 34509.7 | 3.25 |

sheet2

| Transponder | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 34501.6 | 41 |
| 34504.2 | 42 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 34509.7 | 1165 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 34527.9 | 1166 |

Comment: please mock up a dataset and expected output from that dataset.  Just the formula and one input does not help us understand your problem.

Comment: but my guess: `=XLOOKUP(MIN(ABS(sheet1!$K$3:$K$534-G4)),ABS(sheet1!$K$3:$K$534-G4),sheet1!$L$3:$L$534,,0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ABS to find the differences then lookup the Minimum:

```
=XLOOKUP(MIN(ABS(Sheet2!$K$3:$K$534-G4)),ABS(Sheet2!$K$3:$K$534-G4),Sheet2!$L$3:$L$534,,0)
```

[image]

Comment: It throws an error maybe because there are some 0 and - values in my list?

Comment: as you can see, it does not throw an error on my sheet and there are `0` and blanks.  So there must be something else.  Are there text in column K or empty strings`""`?

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you so late. Turns out there were rogue dashes in the columns so it would keep throwing errors, had to replace all with blanks to finally make it work. Thanks for your help!